# What is this error and how do I fix this?

Tags: flutter

I'm currently trying to run a flutter code on Visual Studio code but whenever I try to build the app I run into this message:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_app_desktop.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_app_desktop.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_log.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_log.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_app_options.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_app_options.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_app_common.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_app_common.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_mutex_windows.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_mutex_windows.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_date_provider.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_date_provider.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_heartbeat_controller_desktop.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_heartbeat_controller_desktop.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_log_stdio.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_log_stdio.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d3d7d08a438878e74aeb2cbaaedfc967_flatbuffers.dir_Debug_idl_parser.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'flatbuffers.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d3d7d08a438878e74aeb2cbaaedfc967_flatbuffers.dir_Debug_idl_parser.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\flatbuffers.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_google_services_resource.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_google_services_resource.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_logger.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_logger.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_callback.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_callback.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_cleanup_notifier.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_cleanup_notifier.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_util.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_util.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_heartbeat_storage_desktop.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_heartbeat_storage_desktop.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_scheduler.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_scheduler.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_zlibwrapper.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_zlibwrapper.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_base64.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_base64.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_variant.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_variant.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_variant_util.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_variant_util.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d3d7d08a438878e74aeb2cbaaedfc967_flatbuffers.dir_Debug_util.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'flatbuffers.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d3d7d08a438878e74aeb2cbaaedfc967_flatbuffers.dir_Debug_util.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\flatbuffers.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_reference_counted_future_impl.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_reference_counted_future_impl.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_filesystem_desktop_windows.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_filesystem_desktop_windows.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_thread_cpp11.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_thread_cpp11.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(f6e938409d15d4e67858d89bcb981e00_zlibstatic.dir_Debug_deflate.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlibstaticd.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(f6e938409d15d4e67858d89bcb981e00_zlibstatic.dir_Debug_deflate.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\zlibstaticd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(f6e938409d15d4e67858d89bcb981e00_zlibstatic.dir_Debug_inflate.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlibstaticd.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(f6e938409d15d4e67858d89bcb981e00_zlibstatic.dir_Debug_inflate.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\zlibstaticd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(f6e938409d15d4e67858d89bcb981e00_zlibstatic.dir_Debug_crc32.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlibstaticd.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(f6e938409d15d4e67858d89bcb981e00_zlibstatic.dir_Debug_crc32.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\zlibstaticd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_gzipheader.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_gzipheader.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(f6e938409d15d4e67858d89bcb981e00_zlibstatic.dir_Debug_adler32.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlibstaticd.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(f6e938409d15d4e67858d89bcb981e00_zlibstatic.dir_Debug_adler32.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\zlibstaticd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(f6e938409d15d4e67858d89bcb981e00_zlibstatic.dir_Debug_zutil.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlibstaticd.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(f6e938409d15d4e67858d89bcb981e00_zlibstatic.dir_Debug_zutil.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\zlibstaticd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(f6e938409d15d4e67858d89bcb981e00_zlibstatic.dir_Debug_trees.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlibstaticd.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(f6e938409d15d4e67858d89bcb981e00_zlibstatic.dir_Debug_trees.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\zlibstaticd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(f6e938409d15d4e67858d89bcb981e00_zlibstatic.dir_Debug_inftrees.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlibstaticd.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(f6e938409d15d4e67858d89bcb981e00_zlibstatic.dir_Debug_inftrees.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\zlibstaticd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(f6e938409d15d4e67858d89bcb981e00_zlibstatic.dir_Debug_inffast.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'zlibstaticd.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(f6e938409d15d4e67858d89bcb981e00_zlibstatic.dir_Debug_inffast.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\zlibstaticd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d3d7d08a438878e74aeb2cbaaedfc967_flatbuffers.dir_Debug_idl_parser.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __std_find_trivial_8 referenced in function "struct f_b_flatbuffers::StructDef * * __cdecl __std_find_trivial<struct f_b_flatbuffers::StructDef *,unsigned __int64>(struct f_b_flatbuffers::StructDef * *,struct f_b_flatbuffers::StructDef * *,unsigned __int64)" (??$__std_find_trivial@PEAUStructDef@f_b_flatbuffers@@_K@@YAPEAPEAUStructDef@f_b_flatbuffers@@PEAPEAU01@0_K@Z) [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_cleanup_notifier.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_find_trivial_8 [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_heartbeat_storage_desktop.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __std_find_trivial_1 referenced in function "char const * __cdecl __std_find_trivial<char const ,unsigned char>(char const *,char const *,unsigned char)" (??$__std_find_trivial@$$CBDE@@YAPEBDPEBD0E@Z) [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_core_plugin.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals [C:\Users\YWY\Desktop\project\project\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I have tried recloning the Git Repository and making sure my Java and Gradle are compatible. I have also made sure my Flutter is the newest version, and also run KDiff3 to make sure my cloned git repository is the same as the original repository. I'm doing this with my other groupmates and it seems they are able to build the app perfectly fine, and our set-up is almost identical, so I'm not sure why my app is unable to run.

Comment: It looks like there's some discussion of a very similar issue in similar circumstances here: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10931

Answer (score 0):

If remember correctly a lot of the firebase is not supported for desktop development. but there is a package that called firebase_desktop or something that is wrapper that "should" make firebase work desktop.

Comment: The error comes after using firebase_desktop package